# Convert emoji code into emoticon character in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, emoji

How can i convert this string

```
U+1F600
```

into the resp. emoticon or emoji?

I can do this which works fine:

```
echo "\u{1F600}";
```

But when i try to convert a string containing `U+1F600` into this literal it does not work.

F.e this will yield in

> Invalid UTF-8 codepoint escape sequence

```
$str = "Hello U+1F600";
preg_match("/U\+[0-9a-f]{4,5}/mi", $str, $find);
$text = str_replace($find[0], "\u{".str_replace("U+","", $find[0])."}", $str);

echo $text;
```

So what can i do with the Emoji code in PHP to get the Emoji character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `preg_replace()` :

```
$str = "Hello U+1F600";
$str = preg_replace("/U\+([0-9a-f]{4,5})/mi", '&#x${1}', $str);
echo $str;
```

It will display

```
Hello
```

Comment: Im sorry this will just print ```Hello \u{1F600}``` but will not show the emoji icon.
Whereas ```echo "Hello \u{1F600}";``` will.

Comment: @ivoba Then use `&#x1F600` instead of `\u{1F600}`, i'll update my answer